# How to iterate an item from the list using when condition in ansible

Tags: ansible

```
---
- name: Validate packages
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Gather the rpm package facts
    package_facts:
      manager: auto

  - set_fact:
      pkg_list: "{{ ansible_facts.packages |list |unique }}"

  - debug:
      var: pkg_list
```

```
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0. 0.1] => {
    "pkg_list": [
        "libpeas",
        "startup-notification",
        "system-config-printer-libs",
        "perl-ExtUtils-CBuilder",
        "python3",
        "libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-iscsi-direct",

    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
127.0. 0.1            : ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
127.0. 0.1            : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Below task will provide output for one element, provided a static variable. I need to iterate over multiple elements as it should be dynamic from the list using when condition.

```
  - name: Check whether a package is installed
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages['firefox'] | length }} versions of firefox are installed!"
    when: "'firefox' in ansible_facts.packages"
```

Comment: Do you mean iterate over `pkg_list` array? Or have another list, and for each element, check is it also in the `pkg_list` (thus, installed)?

Comment: I am keying in everything to list called pkg_list, hence I just need to iterate over pkg_list with when condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use loop variables in conditionals:

```
  - name: Check whether a package is installed
    debug:
      msg: "{{ ansible_facts.packages[item] | length }} versions of {{ item }} are installed!"
    when: item in ansible_facts.packages
    loop: "{{ pkg_list }}"
```